# How to install Ruby 1.8.7 on OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew, ruby-1.8.7

I've been looking around for the best way to do this and found an easier way than to install both tcl and tk.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
# Install homebrew
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"

# Install command line tools for Xcode -- requires free Apple ID
http://developer.apple.com/downloads

# Install requirements
brew update
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42 rbenv ruby-build

# rbenv method
CONFIGURE_OPTS="--without-tcl --without-tk" rbenv install 1.8.7-p370

# rvm method
rvm install 1.8.7 --without-tcl --without-tk
```